# What to do if a user accept an empty answer instead of better ones?

Tags: discussion

Referring to this question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2499/2703), which has gathered more than 100 upvotes.

It seems to me that the user accepted an answer [that is not really an answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/is-quantum-computing-just-pie-in-the-sky#comment3329_2552), over other better, more informative ones.

If I remember correctly the user used to accept other answers ( but I don't have the screenshots), then suddenly the accepted answer is changed to the current one, with apparently no justification.

If this situation allows to stand, it will mislead new users who don't know a thing about Quantum Computing. This is detrimental to this site and SE model in general.

What to do with this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original poster may choose what answers to accept or not accept. However, you can show your own appreciation (or lack thereof) by voting. This is precisely the situation that voting is intended to fix!

Downvote if you think it was bad, comment with suggestions to improve, upvote if you think it was good, etc.

But it is up to the OP what answer to select. The user may have "completely unknown reasons" or may truly think that helped them. We don't know. Further, I would encourage you to not call out specific users on meta. There's really no need, and it can lead to argument.

Comment: Of course, a problem with the SE model is that the accepted answer goes first, regardless of how it is voted.  For problem-solving questions, this seems fine: The answer solved the OPs problem. For more opinion-based (or let's say opinion-driven) questions, the OP might be more likely to accept the answer which confirms his opinion, rather the one which is hopefully most scientifically well-funded. -- I admit I don't know of a good solution.  (If there were a way to disable accepting on opinion-driven questions, that might be an option, but afaik that doesn't exist, not even for comm. wiki)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch and thus we run into what the CM's knew all along - SE isn't a good place for opinion based stuff =)

Comment: Indeed. But then again, what to do with the question above (for which it is possible to provide fact-substantiated answers, but the weighing of the facts, and thus the judgement of answers, is ultimately opinion-based)?

Answer (score 1):

Upvote correct answer and downvote incorrect answers, that is all you can do. As an example from SO, consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345175/correct-way-to-free-allocate-the-context-in-the-openssl). I am sort of expert here and I know that the most upvoted answer is correct while the accepted answer is just stupid and plain wrong, but nothing can be done about it.